# HTML progress style bar - how to change the background colour

Tags: html

I have used the following as a 'progress' type bar:

```
<div style="margin: auto; 
            border-radius: 5px; 
            text-align: center; 
            width: 10%; 
            text-align: left; 
            margin: 2px auto; 
            font-size: 0px; 
            line-height: 0px; 
            background: #C7C7C7; ">  
       <div style="border-radius: 5px; 
                   line-height: 0px; 
                   height: 20px; 
                   min-width: 20%; 
                   max-width: 20%; 
                   width: 20%; 
                   background: #62BF2C; "><!---->
       </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way using just HTML to allow the background colour to change based on the % - i.e. if less than 50% it would be one colour if 51%-80% a different colour, if more than this a third colour?

Comment: Easy to achieve with jQuery. Quite not possible with only HTML.

Comment: 100% need to use some kind of script to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible HTML + jQuery solution for your case:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-meter">
    <div class="inner-meter"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-meter {
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 2px auto;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    background: #C7C7C7;
}
.inner-meter {
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 56%;
}
```

jQuery/JavaScript:

```
var meter = $('.inner-meter');
var percent = 100 * meter.width() / $('.outer-meter').width();

if (percent < 50)
{
     meter.css('background-color', 'green');
}
else if (percent > 51 && percent <= 80)
{
     meter.css('background-color', 'orange');    
}
else
{
     meter.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

**Demo JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/v3h3nbny/1/

Comment: the only issue I have found now, is when you want to have multiple bars on the same page :S <div class="outer-meter">
    <div class="inner-meter" style="width:60%"</div>
</div> does not work. It moves the bar, but still colours it based on the css width (take that out and it doesn't work at all!)

Comment: I've found an example on the web and adapted it a little, see if it helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy9cA/245/

Comment: excellent thank you :) I tried to put the <div class="progress_bar" value="16"></div> in a table cell, but only works if set the css width to like 5000%... any ideas why? :)

Comment: Maybe because of "width:10%;" on progress_bar class? (CSS side)

Answer (score 1):

Try using css calc() function to change the background-position of an image (set as background-image of the progress bar container) with different color sections to simulate the bar is changing color.

See:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: He has asked for a plain HTML way. Though your answer just blew my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is just static.

For that purpose, you will need to use javascript/jquery and css.

Comment: Please check the calc() CSS function

Comment: Of course @TelmoDias, but he will need some scripts and CSS, like the one you said, to do it, with just HTML will be not possible at all.

Comment: calc is a CSS function not a JavaScript function. It is written directly in the CSS file or in a CSS statement.

Comment: I know, but that won't make it move with only CSS and HTML

Comment: You are missing the point. The JavaScript may be needed for calculating the percentage for the preloader. But the **question** posted by @Arron was after already having that % , how can you change the background color using **only CSS+HTML based on that percentage**.

Comment: Yes, then if that's the point, he having the %, that will do enough to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)** or **[NProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/)** as they are already programmed, and it should be easier to configure.

**PACE** also supports **themes**, so you can customize it even more!